# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react with UseState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, use-state, array.prototype.map

So I am coding this app in react that allows you to add filters to an image, I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" I am using a functional component with UseState. The default options are the filters. This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Slider from './Slider'
import SidebarItem from './SidebarItem'

const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = [
  {
    name: 'Brightness',
    property: 'brightness',
    value: 100,
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200
    },
    unit: '%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Contrast',
    property: 'contrast',
    value: 100,
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200
    },
    unit: '%'
  },
  //...
]

function App() {
  const { options, setOptions } = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="main-image" />
      <div className="sidebar">
        {options.map((option, index) => {
          return (
          <SidebarItem
            key={index}
            name={option.name}
          />
          )
        })}
      </div>
      <Slider />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Use it like this instead and try: `const [options, setOptions] = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not curly braces when using `useState`. It's an array

```js
const [ options, setOptions ] = useState(DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
```